# Клиентский IP-адрес на RDP-сервере определяется как 127.0.0.1

Tags: windows, домен, rdp

Добрый день. 
Возникла такая проблема: есть RDP-сервер (находится в домене), есть n-ное количество компьютеров (некоторые в домене, некоторые нет). 
Проблема в том, что на сервере в Remote Destop Services Manager'е IP-адреса клиентов определяются по-разному. У кого-то реальны IP-адрес, у кого-то 127.0.0.1, причем какой-либо зависимости не обнаружилось (проверял версию ОС, версию RDP-клиента, установлены ли драйвера на сетевую карту, в домене ли находится комп клиента, антивирус, файрволл и ещё кучу остального). 
Ниже скрины для примера.

[image: Проблемный комп]

[image: Непроблемный комп]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по какой причине это может быть, ну или хотя бы в какую сторону рыть в поисках решения.

Спасибо.